# web scraping results not saving

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, save

In every other tab, index numbers and data coming to txt are reset, I want to save the data to txt one after the other without resetting.

There is no other problem in the codes other than these errors

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv
import re


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url ="http://google.com"
driver.get(url)

searchInput = driver.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
time.sleep(1)
searchInput.send_keys("dişçi")
time.sleep(2)
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
result = driver.page_source
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")

for index,element in enumerate (result):
  print(index+1,element.text)

result = []
result = list(set(result))
 
time.sleep(2)

try:
    while 1:
        nextInput = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]').click()
        result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GyAeWb cite.iUh30")

        for index,elements in enumerate (result):
            print(index+1,elements.text)
        
        count = 1
        with open("siteler.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") as file:
            for item in result:
                file.write(f"{count}-{item}\n")
                count+=1
      
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    print("there is no element with '//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]' XPATH")


driver.close()
```

---

**This is how it registers:**

```
1-<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="488459ee0c4c000e56111d8e98626783", element="35944ab0-591a-48e6-834f-93e3a75a9192")>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but if you want to append entries to a txt file choose the option `a` to append.

Comment: The data I pull is not saved in txt. 
Index numbers and data coming to txt are reset in each tab, I want to save the data to txt one after the other without resetting.

Comment: `open("siteler.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") ` That looks like a txt file that is overwritten in the while loop, to me.

Comment: Can you help if you know the solution for the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in my comment: Use `'a'` instead of `'w'` as an option to open the file

```
with open("siteler.txt", "a") as file:
   ...
```

See also [How do I append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-i-append-to-a-file) since this question might be a duplicate.

Comment: The data captured in this way is written one after the other without resetting. Thank you.
The retrieved data is coming in incorrectly...

1-<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0822a81b89ac6d09aa4209aa28beba33", element="51948d2e-c041-4142-a652-d9b10296c88c")>
2-<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0822a81b89ac6d09aa4209aa28beba33", element="f46667cd-042a-4ef7-92f4-39f95e396423")>
3-<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0822a81b89ac6d09aa4209aa28beba33", element="5a5bda7b-9bd2-4f21-8ce3-3679bb4785aa")>

like this.

Comment: Your answers were very helpful and thanks for the warning.